# How far away is n to the next power of b?

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

Let `n` and `b` be positive integers larger than `1`.

Output the distance from `n` to the next power of `b`.

For `n=5` and `b=3`, the next power of `3` from `5` is `9` (`3^2 = 9`), so the output is `9 - 5 = 4`.

For `n=8` and `b=2`, the next power of `2` from `8` is `16` (`2^4 = 16`), so the output is `16 - 8 = 8`. Note that `n` is a power of `2` in this example.

Testcases:

```
  n b output
212 2 44
563 5 62
491 5 134
424 3 305
469 8 43
343 7 2058
592 7 1809
289 5 336
694 3 35
324 5 301
  2 5 3
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins. [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Answer (score 17):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>4</s>  3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ạæċ
```

A dyadic link taking `n` on the left and `b` on the right and returning the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroWHlx3p/v//v7GRyX9TAA)**

#### How?

```
ạæċ - Link: number n, number b | n,b ∈ ℕ
 æċ - ceiling n to the next power of b
ạ   - absolute difference between n and that
```

Comment: Crossed out 4 is still regular 4 ;(

Comment: @Uriel But `&nbsp;` ;)

Comment: tfw your *initially initial* thought is "oh it's `æċ`!" instead of "oww this is sooo hard..."

Comment: Oh it might not exist in the history, but I did change from a 4 byter. It was `æċ_⁸`

Comment: @JonathanAllan Since it wasn't in the history it didn't make sense and that's why I edited that out.

Answer (score 8):

### x86-64 Assembly ([Windows x64 Calling Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx)), <strike>14</strike> 13 bytes

An inefficient (but svelte!) iterative approach (with credit to @Neil for inspiration):

```
               HowFarAway PROC
6A 01             push   1
58                pop    rax         ; temp = 1
               Loop:
0F AF C2          imul   eax, edx    ; temp *= b
39 C8             cmp    eax, ecx
72 F9             jb     Loop        ; keep looping (jump) if temp < n
29 C8             sub    eax, ecx    ; temp -= n
C3                ret                ; return temp
               HowFarAway ENDP
```

The above function takes two integer parameters, `n` (passed in the `ECX` register) and `b` (passed in the `EDX` register), and returns a single integer result (in the `EAX` register). To call it from C, you would use the following prototype:

```
unsigned HowFarAway(unsigned n, unsigned b);
```

This is limited to the range of a 32-bit integer. It can be easily modified to support 64-bit integers by using the full long registers, but it would cost more bytes to encode those instructions. :-)

Comment: So, you can't set eax to 1 in fewer than 4 bytes?

Comment: Hmm… Not in any of the *normal* ways that a *sane* programmer would use, but you could `push 1`+`pop rax` in only 3 bytes. But… then you wouldn't have to skip the multiplication, so that would still be a reasonable savings because you could drop the `jmp`.

Comment: Ah, I knew there had to be a way to golf a byte off!

Comment: You can do the same with the SysV calling convention on Linux, with a [TIO demo](https://goo.gl/si2usw).

Comment: Of course you can. You can do it with any calling convention that passes at least the first two integer parameters in registers. System V, Win x64, Win32 __fastcall, etc. The registers just change, and I had to pick one. Coin came up "Windows".

Answer (score 6):

## Dyalog APL, 10 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @ZacharyT*

```
⊢-⍨⊣*1+∘⌊⍟
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u22A2-%u2368%u22A3%2A1+%u2218%u230A%u235F%20%u22C4%202%202%205%205%203%20f%208%20212%20563%20491%20424&run)

Takes `n` as right argument and `b` as left argument.

Calculates `b⌊logbn + 1⌋ - n`.

Comment: Nice, I was just about to post this exact solution

Comment: @KritixiLithos I had hard time with the floor trick. you think it could be made into a train?

Comment: Yeah, it can: `⊣-⍨⊢*1+∘⌊⍟⍨`.

Comment: @ZacharyT nice one!

Comment: I get `⊢-⍨⊣*1+∘⌊⍟` for 10 bytes but with swapped arguments so that `n` is the right argument and `b` is the left argument. I used ZacharyT's trick of `1+∘⌊` to get it down this far.

Comment: @KritixiLithos I was just about to update this with the same one

Comment: I was just about to comment the same thing!

Comment: @Jenny_mathy to handle cases where the number is an exact power of the base, like `n=8 b=2`. using ceiling would find `8-8` instead of `16-8`.

Comment: Good job. Nice teamwork.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>39</s> 35 bytes

New undefined behavior thanks to Erik

```c
f(n,b,i){for(i=b;b<=n;b*=i);n=b-n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYhBCsIwEADvfUUoCNmQHGwFD2teojkkq7E5uCmx5FL6bM/RgjAMw5B5ErUWJeugE6wxF5lswHCxjEHZBMg2GMatvXxiSboCTb4oVXHthJhL4iXK/vAWO/cb97pej@6nweko/ZKT3Afofw4OALDbWhtPYzt/OBvyND2@)

Comment: `f(n,b,i){for(i=b;b<n;b*=i);n=b-n;}` saves 5 bytes, and is supported by gcc

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer why not `b-=n`?

Comment: @LeakyNun Because it's the first argument you need to save the return value to.

Comment: Umm, you didn't update the code.

Comment: Can you do `b-=n` if you swap the order of `b` and `n`?

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> 34 bytes

```r
pryr::f({a=b^(0:n)-n;min(a[a>0])})
```

Anonymous function. Stores all values of b to the power of everything in the range [0,n], subtracts n from each, subsets on positive values, and returns the min.

TIO has a non-pryr version, called as `f(n,b)`; this version needs to be called as `f(b,n)`.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam, who then [outgolfed me.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127422/62105)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P802rTQvuSQzP08jTydJszrRNilOw8AqT1M3zzo3M08jMTrRziBWs5aLK03DyNBIx0gTyDA1M9YxBTFMLA0hDCMIZWxkAmT8/w8A)

Comment: Nice, way shorter than the recursion I had in mind.

Comment: `pryr::f({a=b^(0:n)-n;min(a[a>0])})` is a few bytes shorter.

Comment: Thanks. I've had bad luck using `pryr::f` when I define a new variable in the function; looks like it works here.

Comment: Hmm, it's always worth checking :) What annoys me is if you have something like `sapply(x, sum)` or whatever, that it adds `sum` to the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>24</s> 20 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to MickyT*

```
Pwp.I|-.;)^0@O?|uq;<
```

Reads in input like `n,b`

Fits on a 2x2x2 cube:

```
    P w
    p .
I | - . ; ) ^ 0
@ O ? | u q ; <
    . .
    . .
```

#### Explanation:

`I|I0` : read the input, push 0 (counter) to the stack

`^w` puts the IP to the right place for the loop:

- `Pp-` : compute `b^(counter)`, move `n` to top of stack, compute `b^(counter) - n`
- `?` : turn left if negative, straight if 0, right if positive

  - Positive: `O@` : output top of stack (distance) and exit.
  - Negative : `|?` : proceed as if the top of the stack were zero
- `<;qu;)` : point the IP in the right direction, pop the top of the stack (negative/zero number), move `n` to the bottom of the stack, u-turn, pop the top of the stack (`b^(counter)`) and increment the counter
- IP is at `^w` and the program continues.

[Watch it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=UHdwLkl8LS47KV4wQE8/fHVxOzw=&input=MjEyIDI=&speed=20)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z@gvEDPs0ZXz1ozzsDB376mtNDa5v9/I0MjBSMA)

Comment: Using your same procedure, just a different path `Pwp.I|-.;)^0@O?|uq;<`

Comment: @MickyT genius! I feel like every time I submit a cubix answer, you come along and shave off four or five bytes...

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

```hs
n%b=until(>n)(*b)1-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxDsIwEAS/cgWRbLQUPp9NXIRvUKAUiYQUC3OKwDR83hhNs7OabXk/7qW0psM6fbTmYi5qzXG17qTtuWSlifZX1koH@ub9mutGZrB0Y8cI0UOSg7BAYoIXj5AYPCbEJPD957m3CB2PEefOf3Wf2w8)

`until` saves the day

Comment: Augh, I knew there must have been a builtin for that. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 30 bytes

```
pryr::f(b^floor(log(n,b)+1)-n)
```

Evaluates to the function

```
function (b, n) 
b^floor(log(n, b) + 1) - n
```

Which takes the first power greater or equal than `n`, and then substracts `n` from that value.

Changed `ceiling(power)` to `floor(power+1)` to ensure that if `n` is a power of `b`, we take the next power.

Comment: [1 byte shorter](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTSMpTiMnP10jTydJU1Vf1VDbUFM3T/N/moaRjpGhkeZ/AA) using ```%/%1``` instead of ```floor()```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
sLmʒ‹}α¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/2Cf31KRHDTtrz208tOb/f3MuYxNjAA)

**Explanation**

```
s         # swap order of the inputs
 L        # range [1 ... n]
  m       # raise b to each power
   ʒ‹}    # filter, keep only the elements greater than n
      α   # calculate absolute difference with n for each
       ¬  # get the first (smallest)
```

Comment: You beat me by a minute. That's exactly what I wrote, but I used `ć` instead of `¬`.

Comment: @Riley: Also works with filter, but unfortunately doesn't save any bytes.

Comment: @Emigna *unfortunately doesn't save any bytes* *saves byte(s)\*

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Yes, well. It was an additional change utilizing the weird way implicit input works that saved a byte :)

Comment: Do the inputs have to be in that order?

Comment: @carusocomputing: Yes. It actually saves a byte to have them in the *"wrong"* order as I can reuse `n` implicitly, both in the filter comparison and the absolute difference calculation.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
yy:YAn^w-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v7LSKtIxL65c9/9/M0sTLmMA)

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `694` and `3` as an example.

```
y    % Implicitly take two inputs. Duplicate from below
     % STACK: 694, 3, 694
y    % Duplicate from below
     % STACK: 694, 3, 694, 3
:    % Range
     % STACK: 694, 3, 694, [1 2 3]
YA   % Base conversion (of 694 with "digits" given by [1 2 3]
     % STACK: 694, 3, [3 3 2 3 1 2]
n    % Number of elements
     % STACK: 694, 3, 6
^    % Power
     % 694, 729
w    % Swap
     % STACK: 729, 694
-    % Subtract. Implicitly display
^    % 35
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>42</s> 40 bytes

Thanks to commenter @Steadybox for the tip

```
o;p(n,b){for(o=b;n>=b;)b*=o;return b-n;}
```

Comment: Using `for` instead of `while` saves two bytes: `o;p(n,b){for(o=b;n>=b;)b*=o;return b-n;}`

Comment: Suggest `n/b` instead of `n>=b`

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
#2^⌊1/#~Log~#2⌋#2-#&
```

thanks Martin

**I/O**

> [343, 7]
>
> 2058

Comment: You can use `1/Log@##` or `#2~Log~#`. Or even better swap the order of the inputs *and* use `Log@##`.

Comment: And then `#^Floor[...]#` is shorter than `#^(Floor[...]+1)`. And there's the Unicode operators for `Floor` as well.

Comment: yes, yes of course.I'm working on all these.you are quick!

Comment: Don't forget `Log@##`! Actually, if you swap the argument order, `#^⌊Log@##⌋#-#2&` should be possible for -5 bytes (I think)!

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 42 bytes

*Based on [@GovindParmar's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127227/58217).*

```java
n->b->{for(int o=b;n>=b;b*=o);return b-n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZAxb4MwEIX3/IoboSqWAoQGuTBW6tApY9XBEEAmcLbMESmK@O3UlXAydIEbfKdnf372a8VVBEpX2J4vs@y1MgSt1dhIsmP1iCVJhexjGfhOj0UnSyg7MQzwJSTCfQe2Fn0gQbZdlTxDb3e9ExmJzfcPCNMM/nL4r9yV759IVVOZ13/C0vMcashgxiAvgvxeK@NJJFBZwTG3S/GSKZ@bikaDUATIp9l58Ifb6TZQ1TM1EtP2QdShVzOhdXfzwn3ou9H3OaxhDknkmMNaJk7325kwdky0mklSxxzXMlH8@M/b6gzScDMTHtPNGSTp9gyiZ25Pn2k3zb8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2),  <s>42 41</s>  35 bytes

Saved 6 thanks to loopy walt! (A superior recursive algorithm.)

```python
f=lambda n,b:n<1or b*f(n/b,b)-(n%b)
```

A recursive function which repeatedly integer divides by `b` until that yields `0` (`n<1`) yielding `1` (well, `True` which works like `1`) at the tail and multiplies back up by `b` removing the remainder after division by `b` at each step. That is, we subtract `n` from `b^k` in base `b`, "digit" by "digit".

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3LCsMgEEXX7Ve4iyOThaN5GJr@i9KGBloTUhH69VbN6nAuB@7@C6/NU0rL/LYf97DMosM4y4nbWwTBY2thO9jC6y4cpCVreH4DWz3jnCQhAfKuV9hlaiNPkkZV2BscM5VWOJTOUCWNpna9OTuV@w5gul72Y/WhPiBr2nuD@VwUhfQH)**

Comment: https://tio.run/##Jc3LCoMwEIXhdfsUgyAkMr2YizXSPkwGGyq0o9hs@vRpoquPAz@c5RdfM@uUwuPtPzR6YKSB7wSeR6ATw7wCNUHwhZBkCnnG5zfCxCCEahUqicJ2Gm3WuHZXGdTFzmGf1UbjrXRObarebV3n9k7n3ko5HA/LOnEU5QGr@noOVR1EU6aU6Q8 is a bit shorter but having to output the result with format "%.0f" is probably cheating.

Comment: @rici Nice, I think it may be OK to use floating point arithmetic. I'll add it as an alternative (another byte may be saved by switching forms due to `b-n` never being zero at the same time as `n<b` is true).

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##Jc1NDsIgEIbhtZ6CjSnTTGMYfiyNeheIEpsobSobT49AV0@@yZvM@kuvJVLO4fZ2H/9wzKGf3FUsG/N94O7s0cPA3clDDuWYnt/E5sg4J0FIgFwbibqorNglhbJqLI5FqSReamepSaNtnbF7J0uvAabjYd3mmNoHZN1w75AF3tcJ@Q8) (Python2) I believe.

Comment: Much better, thanks @loopywalt (I think I'd have posted as my own if I'd seen this and written that!) Do let me know if you think there is a clearer description or if I have any mistakes.

Comment: Not much glory to earn with very late answers... Re clarity, perhaps mention that we are basically subtracting (from `b^k`) `n` digit-by-digit in base `b`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

Very similar to [Rick's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127232/58974) but posted with his permission (and some help saving a byte).

```
n=>b=>g=(x=b)=>x>n?x-n:g(x*b)
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
n=>b=>g=(x=b)=>x>n?x-n:g(x*b)
oninput=_=>o.value=f(+i.value)(+j.value)()
o.value=f(i.value=324)(j.value=5)()
```

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif;}
input{margin:0 5px 0 0;width:50px;}
```

```html
<label for=i>n: </label><input id=i type=number><label for=j>b: </label><input id=j type=number><label for=o>= </label><input id=o>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 8 bytes

<s>This feels longer than it needs to be!</s> That's a bit better!

```
nVpUìV l
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=blZwVexWIGw&input=MjEyCjI)

```
nVpUìV l     :Implicit input of integers U=n & V=b
n            :Subtract U from
 Vp          :  Raise V to the power of
   UìV       :    Convert U to a base-V digit array
       l     :    Get the length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>34</s> 32+2 bytes

```
{for(n=$2;n<=$1;n*=$2);}$0=n-$11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxLCgIxDAbgfU7RxSxUEPJqp2GsN/AQbgQROqKCC/Hq1unUx7/6QpJ/fz@V8jiMl0VOHQ95kzoa8mrycnh2mPK6o1KY2LFLW6cKPojz1YFBjZpJFJTVSR0EPWgwF@cPAVFxfTWjj@CN20QRDThaaxAJEOzb4EGmtrZAAv4QiEV96KPhX45wTr2wKbEPXoUJfyJ8jefbcczXst69AQ)

Requires the `-M` option for arbitrary precision to handle the `12345678901234567890 1000000 => 999987654321098765432110` case.

The non-loop version requires the same number of bytes:

```
$0=$2^int(log($1)/log($2)+1)-$1
```

After almost 5 years, saved 2 bytes in each formulation by removing unnecessary grouping symbols. Thanks @PaoloVlw

Comment: Aahhh... I see that I may not need the 2 bytes for the "large" answer, since I accidentally grabbed Toby Speight's inputs rather than the original inputs.  Oh well. This should allow it to work for all cases.

Comment: These save both versions 2 bytes each: `{for(n=$2;n<=$1;n*=$2);}$0=n-$1` and `$0=$2^int(log($1)/log($2)+1)-$1`.

Comment: @PauloVlw It's nice to know that someone is still interested in AWK. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
ɾe'¹>;hε
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvmUnwrk+O2jOtSIsIiIsIjM0M1xuNyJd)

Port of 05AB1E.

### How?

```
ɾe'¹>;hε
ɾ        # Inclusive range from one to (implicit) first input
 e       # For each element, push it to the power of the (implicit) second input
  '¹>;   # Filter for only elements greater than the first input
      h  # Get the first item
       ε # Get the absolute difference of the first item and the (implicit) first input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
f(n,b)=b^{floor(log_bbn)}-n
```

[Try It On Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vqju31kztc)

-3 thanks to @Aiden Chow and @Steffan

Gotta love using your favorite graphing calculator for code golf. Taken from the [R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/127422/107299).

Comment: `log_b(n)+1` can be `log_bbn` ([link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vqju31kztc)). btw [aiden chow found this, not me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61047524#61047524)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```
f=(n,b,i=b)=>b>n?b-n:f(n,b*i,i)
```

**Test cases:**

```js
f=(n,b,i=b)=>b>n?b-n:f(n,b*i,i)

console.log(f(212, 2)) // 44
console.log(f(563, 5)) // 62
console.log(f(491, 5)) // 134
console.log(f(424, 3)) // 305
console.log(f(469, 8)) // 43
console.log(f(343, 7)) // 2058
console.log(f(592, 7)) // 1809
console.log(f(289, 5)) // 336
console.log(f(694, 3)) // 35
console.log(f(324, 5)) // 301
```

Comment: You can save a byte by currying (it didn't matter whether I tried currying both `n` and `b` or just `n`), because that saves you from having to pass `n` recursively.

Comment: Thanks @Neil, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that(?)

Comment: The two versions I came up with were `n=>g=(b,p=b)=>p>n?p-n:g(b,p*b)` and `n=>b=>(g=p=>p>n?p-n:g(p*b))(b)`.

Comment: Would `f=(n,i)=>g=(b=i)=>b>n?b-n:g(b*i)` work for 30 bytes? It would need to be called like so: `f(324,5)()`. EDIT: Ah, @Neil beat me to it.

Comment: @Neil, thanks, I need more practice with currying.

Comment: @Shaggy, I think you should post your solution, but use currying to bring it down to 29 bytes:  `n=>i=>g=(b=i)=>b>n?b-n:g(b*i)`

Comment: @RickHitchcock, as long as you don't feel it's too similar to yours?

Comment: Nope, go for it : )

Comment: I've already upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 32 bytes

```matlab
@(n,b)b^(fix(log(n)/log(b))+1)-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI08nSTMpTiMts0IjJz9dI09TH0QlaWpqG2rq5v1P0zAyNNIx0uRK0zA2MtEx1fwPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 26 bytes

```matlab
@(n,b)b^sum(b.^(0:n)<=n)-n
```

[Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/##JU3JqsIwFF17vuJuCgnUktybxEYt@B@PJ1hrwYWpWAfoz9cGV2fgDMP5eXpf5vmgUtnq9ji@bqqtjspsk943Sa/T3DenNO6AqfmrqgpsmZgK5@CDkKciMFy0mVlxcOxIqBDj4UKkekkKxAltqGDja/jImdvaRHAdc08kIMRfz0OWhWwaC1qe/P9uEQD64UEdNWS39Bg@o5o0Vt11vKteTaorrS4zsNYal9TNXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 38 bytes

Two different approaches:

```ruby
->(n,b){p b**(Math.log(n,b).to_i+1)-n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104jTydJs7pAIUlLS8M3sSRDLyc/HSymV5Ifn6ltqKmbV/s/TS85MSdHw8jQSMdIkwvKMzUz1jGF80wsDZF5RiY6xgiemaWOBZxnbGKsY44wxdIIiWdkYYlkipklsinGQDMRckZA9n8A)

```ruby
->(n,b){p b**(0..n).find{|x|b**x>n}-n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf104jTydJs7pAIUlLS8NATy9PUy8tMy@luqaiBihSYZdXq5tX@z9NLzkxJ0fDyNBIx0iTC8ozNTPWMYXzTCwNkXlGJjrGCJ6ZpY4FnGdsYqxjjjDF0giJZ2RhiWSKmSWyKcZAMxFyRkD2fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
_q}a@nVpX
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=X3F9YUBuVnBY&input=MTI3IDI=)

#### Explanation

```
_  q}a@  nVpX
Z{Zq}aX{UnVpX}  // Ungolfed
                // Implicit: U, V = input integers
     aX{     }  // For each integer X in [0...1e9), take
          VpX   //   V to the power of X
        Un      //   minus U,
Z{  }           // and return the first one Z where
  Zq            //   Math.sqrt(Z) is truthy.
                //   Math.sqrt returns NaN for negative inputs, and 0 is falsy, so this is
                //   truthy iff Z is positive. Therefore, this returns the first positive
                //   value of V**X - U.
                // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: ... Wait. What?

Comment: @Shaggy I've added an explanation, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
f n b=[b^x-n|x<-[1..],b^x>n]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrhCoIwGEVf5fOfwlXy21wOshcZC2YkjXTISrDo3dfi/LnncO/u@bjNc0oTBRoHM172Onz3U23aprHIeg62KA5pcT7QQGv04UXl4lYqt3DdYnzTVFH58SsZbhmdEpC6hWQJqTSEFOg0g3sNpSVE7mzzF11GoMcx81/ZbVWlHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>31 30</s>  29 bytes

```perl6
->\n,\b{(b,b* *...*>n).tail -n}
```

[Test it (31)](https://tio.run/##RY7BboMwEETv@xVzSQIECNjGBaFEvfbeI5cYHAmJGAS0ahXly3rrj9ElatXDase7b2Y92LHTy9tk8a7juqTrJ7Z131gcl@hUubAyN8@EJkAQx3Fwcn48n9sOkbsvjD7PdppxRNc6O3n@91dc91fjHapmf1hfL24uaQ1/Za6koTs77B@mki79@OuPTvDAt1AZLvsx2Hq2DXzcCGgnrP/xXGj8EH/LENMwtm6@YLeRDTYpV7MLwSHmn6L7AmSQUByUQyAnkQruSlGmJa@0IFWkLFKpSAnFrEwyUrpgXkmSSuIJIslyygrBMs2TgkRerLFSky4elowke3mUpHxJrOoH)

```perl6
->\n,\b{b**(log(n,b).Int+1)-n}
```

[Test it (30)](https://tio.run/##RY69boNAEIT7fYppHIP5MffDBYRspU2fkibA2ULCBwISJbL8ZOnyYmSxEqVY3dztNzM32LEzy9tk8W7iuqDLJx7qvrE4LNGxdGFZXavdzuv6s@fCyo@f3RwIP3K3hcmn2U4zDuhaZyfP//6K6/5SefuyCfbrjeGC1uwX5goauleH4G4q6NSPv/7oCA9chbLisR@DrWfbwMeVgHbC@p17eYi/ZYhpGFs3n7DdqAYbwdNsQ3BI9U/RbQFSKGgOyiCRkRSST60pNYpXRpLOBQuhNGmpmVVJStrkzGtFSis8QiZpRmkuWYosyUlm@RqrDJn8bklJsZefEsFNclU/)

```perl6
{$^b**(log($^a,$b).Int+1)-$a}
```

[Test it (29)](https://tio.run/##RY7NboNADITvfoo5kAYCIewPWxBK1WvvPUaR@NlUSAQQ0KpVlCfrrS9GTdQqB8tj@5vZ7e3QmPl9tPgwYZnR@QsPZVdZ7OeLcyw2G7fp3lznmAdO4YUv7eQLb@vk15nB58mOE/Zo6taOrvfzHZbduXB3h8rfLRPTGS3Rr8xl1Dd5C/9myujUDX/@7RNcHNoAh4LLfva2nGwFDxcC6hHLb9w2KLwA/8cAYz/U7XTCeqUqrARXtQ7AIcWdousMxFDQHJRAIiEpJHetKTaKT0aSTgULoTRpqZlVUUzapMxrRUorPEJGcUJxKlmKJEpJJukSqwyZ9GaJSbGXV5Hgl@SifgE)

```perl6
{($^b,$b* *...*>$^a).tail-$a}
```

[Test it (29)](https://tio.run/##RY7NaoNQEIX38xRnYRo1xnh/vFEkodvuuwwBf25AMCpqS0vIk3XXF7NjaOlimDMz3zn39nZozPw2WrybsMzo@omnsqssDvPNdc5F4BQ@/DAM/aNzzr1wyutm6@T3mcHnyY4TDmjq1o6u9/0Vlt21cHenarNbppd2ymiJfmUuo77JW2wepowu3fDr3x7h4tQGOBVc9qO35WQreLgRUI9YfuO2QeEF@DsGGPuhbqcL1itVYSW4qnUADin@KbrPQAwFzUEJJBKSQnLXmmKj@GQk6VSwEEqTlppZFcWkTcq8VqS0wh4yihOKU8lSJFFKMkmXWGXIpA9LTIq9vIoEvyQX9QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
f(n,b)=b^logint(b*n,b)-n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
^ʰ↙X>₁-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahjuVKSgq2CUrl9RrmSjkIehF1SrqSgawdiPWrb8Kip6eGuztqHWyf8jzu14VHbzAi7R02Nuv//RytEG@kYGRrF6kSb6piaGYNpE0tDIG2sY2JkAqQtdEzMLIG0uY6xiTGYNrWEqDeysASrM7M0AfONjSC0UaxCLAA)

Takes input as a list `[b, n]`.

```
    >₁     n is strictly less than
^ ↙X       some power of
 ʰ         b,
      -    and their difference is
           the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 45 bytes

```ruby
: f >r 1 begin i * 2dup < until rdrop - abs ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoNAEATvvqLwGFBwVo0bg3/RGI0QdFmVPN/M6mWKoat7WPz2ScYh4DgeDDSejO49TjMTN6TfHU/2eZu@@N4vjoS2W6nVdle8/lqHIfVIOGkMSUOsYykvTx1JJhq5qCgNhTK32UXJtacsLZXS5IZ78KyclMqeXmkvz6gffnRNefwB)

#### Code Explanation

```ruby
: f          # start a new word definition
  >r         # store b on the return stack for quick access
  1          # create a counter to store powers of b
  begin      # start an indefinite loop
    i *      # multiply the counter by b
    2 dup <  # duplicate the counter and n. Check if n is less than the counter
  until      # if it is, end the loop
  rdrop      # remove b from the return stack
  - abs      # subtract and get absolute value (avoid negative)
;            # end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
≠Ω>¹*³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/cGfjw11dj5oa/z/qXHBupd2hnVqHNv///z862kjHyNAoVifaVMfUzBhMm1gaAmljHRMjEyBtoWNiZgmkzXWMTYxjYwE)

```
≠Ω>¹*³      # ¹ and ³ duplicate arguments ⁰ and ², so parses as:
≠Ω>⁰*²²⁰
            # now:
 Ω>⁰*²²     # Ω = Iterate function f until test result t is truthy, starting with x:
      ²     #     x is arg 2
    *²      #     f is *² = times arg 2, so iterating generates power series of arg 2
  >⁰        #     t is >⁰ = greater than arg 1  
            # then:
≠           # get the absolute difference to
       ⁰    # arg 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP>=7.1, 46 bytes

```php
for([,$n,$b]=$argv;0>=$d=$b**$i++-$n;);echo$d;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a14dd9ff733d140df9024c45c4358eccfff5b4e8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>50</strike> 48 bytes

<sup>Thanks to EriktheOutgolfer for saving 2 bytes!</sup>

```python
lambda n,b:b**-~int(math.log(n,b))-n
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtBDoMgEEX3PcXEFVgwAdSKSXsRdKFprDQKhLLpple3YHRWb/7/z33DbI3Ypnu3LcM6PgcwZGzHPKc/bQJahzAXi32hmGJMzUWvzvoAKd@cT5OsM1nxttqgT/DIYcVaynq4QtYFGu/RhSx@qZxQ7jCGyXpwoA0oxRknwHsCqqoFgSpRKdlJvCQgdqolgSaRKOPuthuSH8QbeRi1PA2R3KrvMd7@)

Python doesn't have any fancy log or ceiling builtins, so I just went with the obvious approach with a little bit of golfing flair.

Comment: `import math;lambda n,b:b**-~int(math.log(n,b))-n` saves two bytes and is allowed per meta consensus.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `ceil` would not work.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I wasn't using `ceil` because it doesn't work for powers of `b`, but as @Uriel pointed out importing before still saves a byte.

Comment: You can reformat it to be completely fine: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ8kqSUtLty4zr0QjN7EkQy8nP10DKKqpqZvHlZlbkF9UogAS/89VUARSk6ZhZGikY6Sp@R8A). Just place the `import` after the lambda, and add `f=` in the header.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ah, you are correct! I don't know why that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, <s>74</s> 73 Byte

A straight forward solution, I'm using 10 bytes to ensure that the arguments are treated as numbers, and not strings. Outputs to STDIN.

**Edit: forgot to remove the space in `w=1 n=n+0`, saves one byte**

```lua
n,b=...b=b+0p=b w=1n=n+0while p<=n do p=math.pow(b,w)w=w+1 end print(p-n)
```

#### Explained

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAwDATAr@RoqQYLehDcxxgqKGgMUsnz48z1bRHaC5hZIHk0CDkKKTSPfpzXTrZCqT5kuLd2sD3eSe/J4bnQrpXsPbV1NmiKiGkpMf8)

```lua
n,b=...           -- unpack the argument into the variable n and b
b=b+0             -- set b's type to number
n=n+0             -- set n's type to number
p=b               -- set a variable to track the current value of the powered b
w=1               -- set the nth power
while p<=n        -- iterate untill the current power is greater or equals to n
do
  p=math.pow(b,w) -- raise b to the power w
  w=w+1           -- increment w
end
print(p-n)        -- outputs p minus the following power of b
```

Comment: I don't know Lua that well, but is the space between `1` and `end` needed?

Comment: @ZacharyT In Lua, hexadecimal numbers can be inlined if they start with a number, `1end` would start to be interpreted as the number `1e` then throw an error because `1en` isn't a valid hexadecimal value. This only occure when the letter following the number is `[abcdef]` as other letters can't be interpreted as hexadecimal value -> `w=1while` doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Welcome back to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>48</s> 41 bytes

- @Rod's loop simplification saved 7 bytes!

Full program without recursion or bit twiddling:

```python
i=1;n,b=input()
while n>=i:i*=b
print i-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PW0DpPJ8k2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVSHPzjbTKlPLNomroCgzr0QhUzfv/38jQyMdBSMA)

Input format: `n, b`.

Comment: You can [simplify the loop](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PW0DpPJ8k2M6@gtERDk6s8IzMnVSHPzjbTKlPLNomroCgzr0QhUzfv/38jQyMdBSMA "Python 2 – Try It Online") to reduce 7 bytes

Comment: @Rod Would have never thought of that :). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 23 bytes

```
{p=:^q~p>:|_xp-b|\q=q+1
```

Takes parameter `b` first, then `n`.

### Explanation

```
{       DO
p=:^q   SET p to input b (read as 'a' by QBIC fromt he cmd line) ** q (starts as 1)
~p>:    IF p exceeds 'n' (read as 'b' by QBIC fromt he cmd line)
|_xp-b| THEN QUIT, printing p minus b
\q=q+1  ELSE increase q, re-run
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 73 bytes

```
(defun f(n b)(setq a b)(loop(when(> b n)(return(- b n)))(setq b(* b a))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BDsIgEEX3nmKWMyYuOlAsG@9SFGKTZootjcdHakwM7Oa9/Ly5z9MWc8aHD7tAQAFHuPn0gvG45mWJ@H56wRs4EMLVp30VvHyJflOH58JjYcoY10kSYADuGJjo9De9UdBXRtuuNaxB1cZYGCqjtIJrXbbcGB5sUza2Lavyq97wwfkD)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
[-~]^[:>.]^.[:>:[
```

### Usage

```
   f =: [-~]^[:>.]^.[:>:[
   424 f 3
305
```

### Explanation

Performs `pow(b, ceil(log(n+1)))` where `log` has base `b`.

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 23 bytes

```dc
snsb1[lb*dln!<F]dsFxln-
```

I had hoped to be able to use `Z` to count digits in a given radix, but it seems to count only in decimal.  And we might want a base larger than dc supports.  So this takes the obvious approach of successively multiplying by `b` until a value larger than `n` is reached, at which point we subtract `n` and leave the result at top of stack.

Annoyingly, we need `!<` rather than `>` comparison because the condition excludes an answer of 0.

### Demo

```sh
for i in '212 2' '563 5' '491 5' '424 3' '469 8' '343 7'\
         '592 7' '289 5' '694 3' '324 5' '2 5' \
         '12345678901234567890 1000000'
do printf '%s => ' "$i"; dc -e '?rsnsb1[lb*dln!<F]dsFxln-p' <<<"$i"
done
```

```
212 2 => 44
563 5 => 62
491 5 => 134
424 3 => 305
469 8 => 43
343 7 => 2058
592 7 => 1809
289 5 => 336
694 3 => 35
324 5 => 301
2 5 => 3
12345678901234567890 1000000 => 999987654321098765432110
```

Answer (score 0):

### TXR Lisp, 51 bytes

```
(defun f(n b)(-[(ginterate(op >= n)(op * b)1)-1]n))
```

Legend: [ginterate](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-02F671F4), [op](http://www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html#N-0068EA9D).

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 13 chars, 26 bytes

```
{-⍺-⍵*1+⌊⍵⍟⍺}
```

test:

```
  f←{-⍺-⍵*1+⌊⍵⍟⍺}
  212 f 2
44
  563 f 5 
62
  592 f 7
1809
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 49 bytes

```
f=(n,b)=>b**(m=Math).floor(m.log(n)/m.log(b)+1)-n
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda n,b:b**int(math.log(n,b)+1)-n;import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcxNDsIgEIbhvafoEurYhBmKpcabuIGY2iblJw0bT49lYQLLZ77JG79pDZ7y8nzl3Tj7Np0HO9u@33xizqR12MOHnTd@FfzmH5uL4UhdWXI8ytPCUCAg55e/R0UwVpZatEYJVFtpmCqTJLjXPY2NcdJNT@m2R2e/3rEo/wA)

I really wish `log` was builtin

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa`, 28 bytes

```perl
$.*=$F[1]until$.>$_;$_=$.-$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FT8tWxS3aMLY0ryQzR0XPTiXeWiXeVkVPVyX@/38jQyMFk3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYkAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

```julia
n\b=b^floor(1+log(b,n))-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY67asQwEEX7@YqbLRaJOMF6rlU4TeIiXYoUKZYFi9UGLUI2sgP5e0d5kKkOwznMXD9SHMXntuWj7/3pkqapMHGbpnfmm8z5Xd4uU0FEzChhPKeYw8I4oU5ufBPQYx7LEu7Zc16bZU5xZZH/CnOJeU2ZsWpy9A@oR/7So8dNj4D9/t/aDW8vw@Pr8IRdg8Ap5PMmhYSE1mSsgoGVpJ2oIJQmLTUUVGtIW4cOWpHSCgfI1nRknKwoutaR7FxNlLJk3U9iSNW2rlpRv5Hf9AU)